# Kivy drag and drop from ListView

Tags: python, kivy

I'm attempting to set up a ListView so that

1) When selection is made, that selection is deleted from the ListView

2) A Scatter is created holding a label with the text of the selection

3) Using the same click, the Scatter is dragged across the screen

4) The Scatter is deleted once the click is released.

I did this in tkinter, and I'm trying to transition this to Kivy. For the most part, this is pretty straightforward, but I've encountered a couple of issues. The first issue I have is getting the selection of the ListView. The `on_touch_down` event of the ListView gets fired before the `on_selection_change` event of the ListView's adapter, so if I bind to `on_touch_down`, I get what the previous selection was, not the current one. The second issue is dragging the Scatter. The goal is for the user, in 1 click, to make a selection from the ListView, have a Scatter appear and drag it across the screen, and then have the Scatter be removed when the click is released. I've tried to use `touch.grab()` in the following method that was bound to the ListView's `on_touch_down`

```
def onPress(self, view, touch):
    if view.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        self.floatLayout.add_widget(self.scatter)
        touch.grab(self.scatter)
```

But when I click on the ListView I get a `TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'weakproxy' object` error, despite having `keyScatter: keyScatter.__self__` in my .kv file, and `keyScatter` is the id for `self.scatter`.

Is there a good fix for either issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who attempts to do drag and drop from a ListView, there is good news: a solution exists. To solve this problem, I used methods bound to the `on_selection_change` of the ListView's adapter, the `on_touch_down` of the ListView, and the `on_touch_up` of the Scatter that I was being used for the drag and drop, as in the following code block.

```
self.listview.bind(on_touch_down=self.press)
self.scatter.bind(on_touch_up=self.release)
self.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.selectionChange)

def selectionChange(self, adapter):
    if adapter.selection: #Sometimes the selection was [], so a check doesn't hurt 
        names = adapter.data
        self.scatter.children[0].text = adapter.selection[0].text #My scatter has a label as it's first and only child. Here, I'm changing the label's text
        for j in adapter.data:
            if j == adapter.selection[0].text:
                break
        names.pop(names.index(j))
        self.listview.adapter.data = names
        if(hasattr(self.listview, '_reset_spopulate')): #This is used to reset the ListView
            self.listview._reset_spopulate()

def press(self, view, touch):
    if view.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y) and not touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
        self.scatter.center = touch.pos
        self.floatLayout.add_widget(self.scatter) #The scatter appears on the click
        self.scatter.on_touch_down(touch) #Needs to be called to get the scatter to be dragged

def release(self, scatter, touch):
    if scatter.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y) and touch.grab_current: #Because Kivy's on_touch_up doesn't work like I think it does

        #Do whatever you want on the release of the scatter

        self.floatLayout.remove_widget(self.scatter) #Remove the scatter on release
```